# How to upgrade Polycom IP5000 firmware from 3.2.6 to 4.0.1?

Tags: polycom

Salvete!  I have a Polycom IP5000 Soundstation which loads its 3.2.6 sip.ld file from my server's polycom ftp directory - no problem there.

However, I want to upgrade the firmware to 4.0.1b or better.  I have read through the [documents](http://community.polycom.com/t5/VoIP/Upgrading-firmware-from-SIP-3-2-6-to-UC-4-0-1/td-p/7260), which give directions, but not enough for my hard head - I just can't get the new configuration to take.

Here is where I stand:
- First, I am using a macaddress configuration - that is, my phones load their settings information from .cfg.
- In the ftp directory, I have sip_326.ld and sip_326.ld which is being used now.
- There is also sip_401b.ld and sip_401b.cfg which I want to upgrade too.
- In the ftp directory (everything is at root), I have also placed the 4.4.0 BootRom files, which look like this:

```
bootrom.ld
2345-12360-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12365-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12375-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12450-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12500-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12560-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12600-001.bootrom.ld
2345-12670-001.bootrom.ld
```

It seems to me that the IP5000 should, using its 3.2.6 configuration, see the bootrom upgrade files in the polycom directory and just load them.  After that, I think I ought to be able to reboot the phone with the 4.0.1 configuration.
Now, what step am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe this should be posted on ServerFault, instead?  If so, perhaps a nice mod could migrate it for me.  Otherwise, I welcome any advice here!

Comment: Help if you post the directions for us.  Indiciate which step does not make sense.

Comment: I was hoping to attract someone who had done it before!  I'll add the link to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - figured it out.  I put the 4.3.0 Bootrom in the ftp directory (it would not work with the 4.4.0 Bootrom).  Then I also put the files for UC Software 3.3.2.  Apparently, I was not able to go directly from 3.2.6 to 4.0.1.  But I was able to go from 3.2.6 to 3.3.2 to 4.0.1.

So I judge that it is a matter of the right order of upgrading.  It does say that in the manuals, but there are so many different versions of everything out there, and so many pdfs to read it is hard to decipher.

To upgrade, you don't have to do much.  In the newer versions, they don't call it `BootRom` anymore - they call it `Upgrader`.  You put the new "upgrader" files in the polycom ftp directory.  That's it.

The upgrade consists in the phone updating its own "brain-reading" files that are kept inside itself.  These will allow the phone to read the sip.ld files that you get from polycom, which are the "brain" of the phone. For the upgrade process, the phones do not boot from the "upgrader" - they boot from their regular sip configurations, that is, the sip.ld file and its accompanying sip.cfg file.  After that, they check to see if any upgrader files are present, and then they load those too.  Once those are loaded into the phone, you don't need the upgrader files any more unless you need to upgrade other phones.  If you have old phones (who are not capable of the new bootrom), they will make an attempt at the upgrade and then ignore it, so you can save your phones some hassle by removing the bootrom-upgrader when you are finished.

So that makes three things:
- sip.ld -->this is the phone's brain, which it loads each time it is booted.
- sip.cfg-->the configuration file for the sip.ld.
- bootrom -->the "brain-reader" that is loaded into the phone so it can read the .ld files.

Don't forget, you still need to point your phone to use a sip.ld and a sip.cfg that will work for your model of phone, and for your new bootrom.

**[update]**
Another thing to notice is that any phone using UCS 3.3.x and upwards will no longer use your sip.cfg or phone1.cfg and will either manually convert your files or utility the cfcUtility that comes with the UCS Download.  For those phones, you need to remove their .cfg files so the phone will use 000000000000.cfg instead.  000000000000.cfg will direct the phone to use a particular sip.cfg and particular sip.ld because the phone will look up its model number there.  A line from 000000000000.cfg looks like this:

```
<APPLICATION_SPIP601 APP_FILE_PATH_SPIP601="sip_318.ld" CONFIG_FILES_SPIP601="phone1_318.cfg, sip_318.cfg"/>
```

Hope that helps a little bit!